# Sending message from pandas dataframe via telegram bot

Tags: python, pandas, telegram-bot

I have scraped a vacancy website and stored the data in csv (for now) and want to send it as a message to a user via telegram bot.

I managed to send one vacancy at each time but couldn't figure out how to send all the vacancies to user.

This is the sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'position': ["a", "b", "c", "d"],

                   'salary': [2, 5, 3, 1],

                   'website_link': ["link1", "link2", "link3", "link4"]})
df
```

How can I send each row separately as a message?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know how to write the function to send the message and you are looking only for the code to style the df to send it row by row.

Here is how I would do it:

```
#Create the message 
code_html='*Title of the message*'  
if df.empty == False:
    for i in range(len(df)):
        code_html=code_html + '\n\n Position:' + str((df['position'].iloc[i])) +'\n Salary: ' + str((df['salary'].iloc[i])) +'\n Web link: ' + str((df['website_link'].iloc[i]))
```

Is this what you are looking for?

If you do a print:

```
print(code_html)

*Title of the message*

 Position:a
 Salary: 2
 Web link: link1

 Position:b
 Salary: 5
 Web link: link2

 Position:c
 Salary: 3
 Web link: link3

 Position:d
 Salary: 1
 Web link: link4
```